# Xcode 7 - native watchkit app , how to?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, xcode7

As you may know, as of Xcode 7 beta and watchOS 2.0 you can build native watch apps.

The thing is i am a complete beginner. I would like to make a simple app that displays a string on the watch screen when the user clicks a button. Then, the user clicks the button again , the string is removed and is replaced by another one (user hits next and sees another string and so one) - all this happening on a single view/screen.

I searched the web for hours and found nothing on building native watch kit apps.

Can anyone give specific instructions on how to do it?

Code examples would also be nice. Also would be nice for someone to explain to me the practical difference between native and non-native watch kit app so i can adapt to the tutorials on the net about (dependent) watchkit apps.

For example,i made a simple hello world for iPhone that alerts the user when he hits a button, but i have no idea how to make a native watch app out of it.

I plan to use Objective C because i know a little bit of C already (and kinda like it).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, visit https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/navigation/ .
Theres plenty of nice guides and code examples there.

As for your question about native vs non-native: Plain and simple, the watch can do more things by itself native. Without the need of communicating with the companion app all the time.

Read the programming guide provided by apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html

Comment: Thank you , i already encountered those , but they are not very useful for me because i am a complete beginner and never developed on iOS or watch. What i would like to know is - what files do i need to modify (as in insert logic code) at the minimum in Xcode to get a native app . Even if it's native do i still need a main app? For example - for a iOS hello world app i modified ViewController.swift and Main.Storyboard from the folder with my app name. In the same way , could you provide an example for apple watch native? Where/what do modify and the connections between files if needed(import)

Comment: If you've never created even an iOS app, you need to start with some basics before diving into something like a WatchKit app.